# Storing each checkboxlist item into its own variable in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to store each checkbox value into its own variable so that I can add that variable to a column on my SQL Server database.

Is there anyway I can set up the 'for each' loop so that when it reads a value from the checkbox list, it stores the value in a string variable named after the value?

i.e. string garden = "garden";  **//if the garden checkbox has been checked**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList  ID="chkAmenities"   RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Furnished</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Parking</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Garden</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Terrace/Balcony</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Wifi</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Heating</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you can get the selected item and store value to its own variable

```
string Furnished = string.Empty;
        string Parking = string.Empty;
        string Garden = string.Empty;
        string Terrace = string.Empty;
        string Wifi = string.Empty;
        string Heating = string.Empty;

        List<ListItem> selectedItem = chkAmenities.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Selected).ToList();
        foreach (ListItem item in selectedItem)
        {
            switch (item.Text)
            {
                case "Furnished": Furnished = "Furnished"; break;
                case "Parking": Parking = "Parking"; break;
                case "Garden": Garden = "Garden"; break;
                case "Terrace/Balcony": Terrace = "Terrace/Balcony"; break;
                case "Wifi": Wifi = "Wifi"; break;
                case "Heating": Heating = "Heating"; break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but why you just don't use a dictionary instead? You can make it as simple as this :

```
var items = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach(ListItem v in chkAmenities.Items)
{
    items.Add(v.Value, v.Text);
}
```

So you can refer every items with : **items["Parking"]** for example.

Just an alternative solution from me.

Comment: Thanks! this is an efficient way of doing it and didn't know much about dictionaries.